# Get ID names of documents using casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I my project, I get `mongodb` data using `casbah`.

```
    val mongoClient = MongoClient()
    val db = mongoClient("configServerTest")
    val coll = db(moduleName)
    val allDocs = coll.find()
    allDocs.foreach(allDocs => println(allDocs))
```

The result is

```
{ "_id" : "version" , "data" : "0.0.1"}
{ "_id" : "portNum" , "data" : 7001}
{ "_id" : "url" , "data" : "http://localhost"}
```

But I need only to get `_id` names as a `list`. How can I do it using casbah ?

```
("version","portNum","url")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this from the [api doc](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection).

```
def find[A, B](ref: A, keys: B)(
    implicit arg0: (A) ⇒ commons.TypeImports.DBObject, 
    arg1: (B) ⇒ commons.TypeImports.DBObject): CursorType
```

Queries for an object in this collection.

An empty DBObject will match every document in the collection. Regardless of fields specified, the _id fields are always returned.

so

```
val allDocs = coll.find(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject())
```

Comment: It's worked in this way

`   val query = MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1)
    val allDocs = coll.find(new BasicDBObject(), query)`

Comment: To clarify that, the **second** document is the [Projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections) where you define the fields you want to return.

Comment: @Shashika and actually if your **projection** contains `{ _id: 0 }` then the `_id` field **is** omitted.